# How to aggregate multiple geolocated model in Autodesk Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have two files (`.skp`).

The first file (`.skp`) is Terrain data.
The second file (`.skp`) is BIM data.
I wanna display two data in the right location.

Through FME translation .skp has geolocated data.

Using Forge Derivative API convert from .skp to .svf

And I can view my two models in Forge Viewer (v7)

Forge Viewer recognize that two model have geolocateddata.(Using this code - `viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Geolocation').hasGeolocationData();`)

I follow this method for load two models in one Forge Viewer.
https://gist.github.com/yiskang/c404af571ba4d631b5929c777503891e

Let's explain with images.

[image]
First. Terrain Mesh only at Forge Viewer
You can see Geolocated and No.0, No.1 Points coordinates(lon/lat/height).

[image]
Second. Revit BIM only at Forge Viewer
You can see also geolocated and No.0 , No.1 Points coordinates.
You have to remember BIM coordinates lon, lat is almost same with Terrain's No.0 Point Coordinate.

[image]
Third(Final). Terrain Mesh + Revit BIM aggregate at Forge Viewer.
Also, have geolocated but if normal BIM model has to placed near No.0 Point(Peak of the mountain).
BIM model is afloat in the air. One more thing. geocoordinates No.1 Point(i picked BIM model) is different from the Second case.

Why this happen??

Comment: Hi, could you share a none-confidential reproducible case that contains both models and a simple runnable viewer app demonstrating this issue for our investigation to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com? I guess that your models are applied with correct ref point data (Revit Shared Coordinate System). They are N/A in your snapshots.

Comment: i have same issue